# C# & SQL Server : inserting/update only truly executes when debugging

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a rather simplistic API for adding, and then later updating a small table in SQL Server. It will insert (or update, which exhibits the same odd behavior) when I step into my data access code in the debugger, but not when I step over that same code. Surely, I've missed something obvious...

```
int result = 0;
const string sql = "INSERT into MyProgress (ImportJobId, SiteCode, ProcessedAmount, TotalToProcess, ErrorCount, CreatedDateTime, LastModifiedDateTime) " +
                   "VALUES (@importJobId, @siteCode, @currentProgress, @totalPieces, 0, getdate(), getdate())";

using (var connection = GetSqlConnection())
using (var sqlCmd = GetSqlCommand(connection, sql))
{
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@importJobId", importJobId);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@siteCode", siteCode);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentProgress", currentProgress);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalPieces", totalPieces);

    //SqlParameter outputParameter = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
    //outputParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
    //sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(outputParameter);

    sqlCmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery();
    //result = (int) (outputParameter.Value ?? -1);
}

return result;
```

For the curious, `GetSqlConnection()` looks like this:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString);
connection.Open();
return connection;
```

Comment: We need to know the value of `_ConnectionString`.

Comment: Where is the call to EndExecuteNonQuery? See the example for [BeginExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca56w9se(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) on MSDN

Comment: No, _ConnectionString is fine. If there was anything wrong with _ConnectionString, it would ~never~ insert data. Paddy solved the problem (see accepted answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BeginExecuteNonQuery()` is an asynchronous method. It will return immediately, before the command is executed. To wait for it to complete, use [`EndExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.endexecutenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

> When you call BeginExecuteNonQuery to execute a Transact-SQL statement, you must call EndExecuteNonQuery in order to complete the operation. If the process of executing the command has not yet finished, this method blocks until the operation is complete.

It seems you're looking for synchronous method. If that's the case, simply use

```
sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This one will return only after the command is executed.

If you want to execute the command asynchronously, it's much easier to use the [`ExecuteNonQueryAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223678(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
await sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

Note that you will have to make your method `async` to use `await`. You also need .NET 4.5+ to use it.

Answer (score 4):

Edited to correct mistakenly calling this an async method - see comments.

---

You are calling the method BeginExecuteNonQuery which initiates a query, but you must call EndExecuteNonQuery to complete the operation (generally asynchronously). When you debug, this has a chance to complete as you manually step through. When you step over, the connection is disposed prior to completing.

You will need to either update your code to use an Asynchronous Programming Model ([APM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx)) pattern or call the synchronous ExecuteNonQuery instead.

Comment: You can't await `BeginExecuteNonQuery`. It returns `IAsyncResult`, not a `Task`. I think you meant `ExecuteNonQueryAsync`.

Comment: @JakubLortz - apologies, you are correct.  Answering things from home when half asleep...

Comment: @Paddy so you acknowledge your question has incorrect information but you don't fix the incorrect information?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - I thought that Jakob (initial commenters) correct answer below would be sufficient.  Hopefully the OP has the nous to change the selected answer.

Comment: Other future visitors may only read the accepted answer, it would be best if you made the accepted answer actually correct.

Comment: I have updated the correct answer to Jakob, as @Paddy requests -- although my original problem was just not realizing I'd chosen the asynchronous execute. I really just wanted the synchronous call -- woops! The problem really was solved by pointing out that I was attempting an asynchronous call. Not a technically glamorous win, but still a win :)